# Unable to start heroku with ruby on rails. Digest/SHA2 no such file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

So i've been making a basic app on my local machine and I cant get it to transfer over to Heroku easily. The server crashes when I try to run it.

When I type heroku run rails s, it boots for a second and then spits out a huge stack trace.

At the top its says :


/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/depenencies.rb:317:in 'rescue in depend_on': No such file to load -- Digest/SHA2 (loadError):

I use the SHA2 for authentication, and it seems to be crashing the application. does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because it's a case-sensitive filesystem, where your local system isn't.

Try changing the require to this:

```
require 'digest/sha2'
```